# "The prices of medical supplies got higher, leading to more COVID cases."

Tags: relative-clauses, participle-clauses

Can a whole sentence work as a subject of present participle clause? Can I write like this (is this grammatically correct)?

> The prices of medical supplies got higher, leading to more COVID cases.

(the main clause as a whole works as the subject of "leading")

Or should I use relative pronoun and write like this?

> The prices of medical supplies got higher, which led to more COVID cases.

Comment: Syntactically, either is fine.

Comment: Thanks. So, this isn't one kind of a dangling participle, is it?

Comment: @Oden-kun Both are correct, read more here: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/participle-clauses

Comment: You should say "increased" instead of "got higher," but otherwise both forms work.